# Wordpress homepage changes not works

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website, I created a customized php template to the homepage and loaded from the back-end in the template page settings.
During the last months everything was working perfectly when I change anything to the template code effects the homepage without any problems.

Suddenly, yesterday when I tried to upload a updated file, nothing changed on the homepage.
I remove the browser cache, and wordpress cache, used another device to check, without any luck.

The wordpress black admin tools bar appears on all sites pages so I can edit and control this page, but it's not appears on the homepage.

For sure I checked again the theme settings for the homepage and page template settings, and everything is correctly configured.

I tried to activate another theme, the surprise that I found the homepage still the same and all other pages changed to the new theme.

I am losing my mind due to this, and I don't understand what may happened.

Answer (score 0):

Download your site on your computer and see whether it happens also on your own computer when simulating with XAMPP.
Are you sure that the new added files are really being uploaded to the server? did you check it up with downloading the files? Maybe the modified files could not been uploaded? Another thing would be that some new installed plugins are making those problems. Have you installed some new plugins like a plugin which are speeding up your wordpress site? There are some popular plugins which speed up your site with caching your whole site and working as a CDN.
Since i dont know which modification you do on your website it is difficult to find a solution. If those modifications are changes of articles then look into the database.
You could look into the SQL Database whether those new information are being saved. E.g. you try to post a new article. Is this article being saved in the SQL database? Do you see any errors on the page? Does this effect each page / section of your website or is it only for a specific module e.g. "image uploader"??
Did you try to replace a simple image on your site with another image ? Can you see the difference on the website? I would start with little steps to be sure whether this is a server issue, template issue or sth with unsufficient priviliges. There were also new wordpress updates, maybe they affected your template? Another thing would be to recover your complete site from a backup and see whether it works like before and be sure that your site has not been hacked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check and see on my local PC

Comment: You can also turn on the errors on your website to see whether there are any errors in your script. However you should do this only on test sites and not on a productive site because this can be seen by everyone who is visiting your site.